# text/template: space in map's key

Tags: templates, go

I have the following code (using `text/template`):

```
inventory := map[string]string{"name of the movie": "hello"}
tmpl, err := template.New("test").Parse("Movie name ") // I want to display "hello" there
if err != nil { panic(err) }
err = tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, inventory)
if err != nil { panic(err) }
```

As you can see, there is spaces in my map's key `name of the movie`. How can I do in the parse argument to display `hello` (which is the value of `name of the movie`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the index function: `Movie name: {{index . "name of the movie"}}`

From [the docs](http://godoc.org/text/template#hdr-Functions):

```
index
  Returns the result of indexing its first argument by the
  following arguments. Thus "index x 1 2 3" is, in Go syntax,
  x[1][2][3]. Each indexed item must be a map, slice, or array.
```